# VBA Set Multiple Filters

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I've used filters manually, but never with VBA.

I have the following:

```
K2 - Item 1
L2 - Item 2
M2 - Item 3
N2 - Item 4
O2 - Item 5
P2 - Item 6
Q2 - Item 7
R2 - Item 8
S2 - Item 9
T2 - Item 10
```

then underneath each user with their Item. Some may have multiple items (i.e. P, R, S & T).

I want to create a "Drop down" (Which I can do haha) where it'll have the 10 Items in it, and when you select an Item, it sets all the filters to blank, but the one Item it, that's been selected, is the only one showing.

Currently doing it manually, but doing it for 10 different items is becoming a head ache!

Just looking to see if someone can point me in the right direction before I spiral down the rabbit hole?

Cheers

Edit:

Have started to try this code, and it does work, but takes forever to process (Downside of having 20k+ lines of data to sift through!)

`````
Sub FilterMasks(mask As String)
    Dim LastRow, RunningNum
    
    LastRow = Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For RunningNum = 3 To LastRow
        Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If mask = "Type" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    
        If mask Like "Item 1" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum)) = 1 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("L" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 2" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":K" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("M" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 3" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":L" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 4" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":M" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("O" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 5" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":N" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("P" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 6" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":O" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Q" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "item 7" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":P" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("R" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 8" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":Q" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("S" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 9" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":R" & RunningNum)) > 0 Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("T" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        
        If mask Like "Item 10" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":S" & RunningNum)) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub````

But I have Filters on all the Headers, was wondering if it'd be smarter to use the Filters rather than the above code!

If so, where would I look at to play around with filters?
`````

Comment: Should add, I did try the following;

`
    For RunningNum = 3 To LastRow
        If mask Like "Item 1" Then
            If IsEmpty(Range("J" & RunningNum & ":T" & RunningNum)) = True Then
                Sheets("Output").Rows(RunningNum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If`

But it didn't work either, did an individual if loop for each Item too

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63265659/edit) your question and place the code inside. Also, a picture will help here, a lot. It's a bit unclear what you want to do exactly, at least to me.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman have edited my original post with the current code I'm using!

I do have filters on all the headers, and am sick of turning them all to blank, but one. Was trying to speed it up via VBA if possible, but unsure if you can use VBA to work with filters. If you can, where would be a good starting place!

Comment: I'd use  `Sheets("Output").AutofilterMode = False` and then place the filter on the corresponding column with it's criteria. Way easier and faster than this.

Comment: @Damian, I want to filter out 11 Columns worth of information basically. So if it only has 1 bit of information in a certain Column, it displays that row.

The certain information is up to the user. They have a drop down selection of the 11 Headers, and which ever one they select, it shows all that have that item, and only that item

Comment: In other words... you want to filter 1 column, the one selected on the dropdown list, but first you need to remove all the current filters and only keep the one they selected. Did I get that right @PCosmo?

Comment: [link]https://i.imgur.com/fJlgQhF.png[/link]

Want Range("J1") to be set to the items, (Each individual color is the item) to only show if that is the only one that has information in it. So for example, if Range("L2") is what is selected, in J1 Cell, it'll only show L column, where J:K & M:T are blank, and L has information in it.

Comment: @PCosmo - Create A Before and After example including actual (fake) data and place that/those picture(s) in your post. It's not clear at all how you are trying to filter, to me at least, via your words.